# Remove numbering from References after Appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, sectioning, numbering

I have a document with an appendix and a bibliography after that. Now I want the References to appear in the ToC. Using
`\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}`
in the preamble does that, but it gives a section number to References (`B` in my case, as the appendix resets section numbering, and then the appendix is `A` and the references get `B`). I want References to appear in the ToC without any such numbering. How can I do that?
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\appendix

\section{Appendix}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` ?

Comment: Oh yes that works, I guess I could've thought of that given the argument is named 'numbib' haha. Thank you!